# Terraform - Dynamic block - For_each not looping through all elements

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to setup dynamic block based on contents in local.tf example shown below

```
locals {
  test_filters = {
    Filter1 = {
      finding_criteria = {
        criterion = {
           field  = "region"
           equals = ["eu-west-1"]
         },
         criterion = {
            field  = "region1"
            equals = ["eu-west-2"]
         }
      }}
    }
  }

resource "aws_guardduty_filter" "test-filters" {
  for_each = local.test_filters
  name = "test"
  action      = "ARCHIVE"
  detector_id = detector_test.detectorid
  rank        = 0
  dynamic  "finding_criteria"{
    for_each = each.value.finding_criteria
    content {
      criterion {
        field = finding_criteria.value.field
        equals = finding_criteria.value.equals
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This code runs but it does not add finding criteria for both the elements present in local.tf under test_filters. It looks like its looping thru the list, but only keeps the data for last element.

```
  # aws_guardduty_filter.test-filters["Filter1"] will be created
  + resource "aws_guardduty_filter" "test-filters" {
      + action      = "ARCHIVE"
      + arn         = (known after apply)
      + detector_id = "xxxx"
      + id          = (known after apply)
      + name        = "test"
      + rank        = 0
      + tags_all    = (known after apply)

      + finding_criteria {
          + criterion {
              + equals     = [
                  + "eu-west-2",
                ]
              + field      = "region1"
              + not_equals = []
            }
        }
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

I tried many things like rearranging the data in local file, adding nested dynamic block etc. But it does not seem to work. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of issues here:

- You're using the same key `criterion` twice in the `local` variable map, so it overwrites one of the entries
- You need to `for_each` the `criterion` rather than the `finding_criteria`

Try something like:

```
locals {
  test_filters = {
    Filter1 = {
      finding_criteria = {
        criterion1 = {
          field  = "region"
          equals = ["eu-west-1"]
        },
        criterion2 = {
          field  = "region1"
          equals = ["eu-west-2"]
        }
      }}
  }
}

resource "aws_guardduty_filter" "test-filters" {
  for_each = local.test_filters

  name = "test"
  action      = "ARCHIVE"
  detector_id = "test-id"
  rank        = 0

  finding_criteria {
    dynamic "criterion" {
      for_each = each.value.finding_criteria
      content {
          field  = criterion.value["field"]
          equals = criterion.value["equals"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```